# Is the equivalence of axial vectors with skew symmetric tensors in 3 dimensions a coincidence?

Tags: electromagnetism, cosmology, tensor-calculus, spacetime-dimensions

We happen to live in the only number of (large space-like) dimensions that permits an equivalence between skew symmetric tensors, like the magnetic field, and vectors. Similarly (equivalently? not sure) we live in the only dimension with a defined cross product that maps two vectors to a third.

Are there any theories as to whether this privileges three dimensional space in some way, or makes it necessary for a stable universe to form? Or is it to our best knowledge just a coincidence?

Comment: It is a special case of the duality correspondence associating $k$-forms to $(n-k)$-vectors. If $n=3$ and $k=1$ you have the identification you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it's useful to make a distinction between vectors and *pseudo*vectors (sometimes called polar vectors and axial vectors, respectively).  Both objects transform the same way under rotations of the basis vectors, but pseudovectors get an additional minus sign under inversions which change the handedness of the basis.

As an example, consider two coordinate bases $\hat x,\hat y, \hat z$ and $\hat u,\hat v,\hat w$, where
$$\hat u = -\hat x$$
$$\hat v = -\hat y$$
$$\hat w = -\hat z$$

If $\hat x,\hat y, \hat z$ is the standard right-handed basis, then $\hat u,\hat v, \hat w$ is a left-handed basis (which you can check via the right-hand rule).  Given any vector $\mathbf R$, we should be able to expand it terms of either basis:

$$\mathbf R = R_x\hat x + R_y \hat y + R_z \hat z= R_u \hat u + R_v \hat v + R_w\hat w$$
In order for this equality to hold, we must have that
$$R_u = -R_x$$
$$R_v = -R_y$$
$$R_w = -R_z$$

As it turns out, this is not true of all objects which can be written as a linear combination of basis vectors.  In particular, it is not true of the angular momentum $\mathbf L = \mathbf r \times \mathbf p$; if $\mathbf r$ and $\mathbf p$ behave like true vectors, then we find that $L_u = L_x$, $L_v=L_y$, and $L_w=L_z$.  The angular momentum $\mathbf L$ is a pseudovector.  The same must be true e.g. of the magnetic field $\mathbf B$, in order for the Lorentz force on a particle to be a vector.

---

In this sense, the cross product doesn't really map two vectors to a vector - it maps two vectors to a *pseudovector*$^\dagger$, and it is the set of pseudovectors which can be put into correspondence with the skew-symmetric tensors.  In many ways it is more natural to think of $\mathbf L$ as a skew-symmetric tensor (also called a [bivector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bivector)).  If we define the [wedge product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra) of basis vectors where $\hat x \wedge \hat y = -\hat y \wedge \hat x$, then we find that $\mathbf L = \mathbf r \wedge \mathbf p$ has the correct transformation properties under both rotations and inversions.

It's perfectly possible to use this definition of $\mathbf L$ to formulate rotations in mechanics.  If you try it out, it's actually fairly straightforward - the operational difference between working with $\mathbf r \wedge \mathbf p$ and $\mathbf r \times \mathbf p$ is quite minimal.

The fact that there is a correspondence between the skew-symmetric tensors and pseudovectors is an accident of 3 dimensions.  The dimensionality of the vector space of skew-symmetric $2$-tensors in $n$ dimensions is $n(n-1)/2$, while the dimensionality of the vector space of (pseudo)vectors is $n$.  Equating the two, the only solutions are $n=0$ and $n=3$. In higher (or lower) dimensions, there is no such correspondence.  For $2$-dimensional systems, the space of skew-symmetric $2$-tensors is only $1$-dimensional, while for $1$-dimensional systems it is $0$-dimensional.

---

Ultimately, it is my opinion that the only reason to introduce cross products and pseudovectors in the first place is because they are easier to explain to students than wedge products and $2$-tensors are$^{\dagger\dagger}$.  Mechanics (and physics more generally) is naturally formulated in terms of the latter, and it is my personal preference to treat angular momentum as a bivector $\mathbf L = \mathbf r \wedge \mathbf p$.

The fact that it is *possible* to find a representation of angular momentum as a pseudovector is an accident of working in 3 spatial dimensions, and we as a community exploit this accident to avoid discussions about tensors with young students.  In particular, being unnecessary (and in my view somewhat unnatural), it does not place any mathematical constraints on the universe, or bestow any particular physical significance on $d=3$.

---

$^\dagger$Or a pseudovector and a vector to a vector, or two pseudovectors to a pseudovector.

$^{\dagger\dagger}$This may be a debatable point.